# Motor doesn't return all documents in the collection. How to fix?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-asyncio

Trying to query entire collection with motor and it stucks on 102 docs. (collection includes ~4k). What it cause of it? Any help appreciated!

```
class MongoConnection(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = AsyncIOMotorClient(config("MONGO_URI"), io_loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())

async def migrate_incidents():
    count = 0
    async for incident in MongoConnection().client.fatboy.incidents.find():
        count +=1
        print(count)
```

Comment: What documentation are you following and what does it say is the correct usage?

Comment: @D.SM https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial-asyncio.html

Comment: hm it working fine after I removed this piece of code:                                                  `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        if loop.is_closed():
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()`